# Using custom functions in Volt force apache process to die

Tags: phalcon, volt

I worked with Phalcon and Volt under WAMP. Recently we moved to another dev environment (CentOS) and there I have PHP 5.5.17 with latest Phalcon build (I compiled and tested 2 versions lower as well).

Now, when Volt tries to compile template with custom function, it crashes (PHP process). The same is 
about custom filters.

Error log of Apache

```
[Tue Sep 30 06:06:24.809476 2014] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 31199:tid 140596014397184] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 10.0.2.2:53931] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :3080:
[Tue Sep 30 06:06:27.216226 2014] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 31200:tid 140596161255168] [client 10.0.2.2:53941] AH01067: Failed to read FastCGI header
[Tue Sep 30 06:06:27.216249 2014] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 31200:tid 140596161255168] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 10.0.2.2:53941] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :3080:
```

PHP error log

```
[30-Sep-2014 06:06:27] WARNING: [pool www] child 32519 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 204.725812 seconds from start
[30-Sep-2014 06:06:27] NOTICE: [pool www] child 32529 started
```

PHP code looks like

```
$di->set('view', function () use ($config) {
    $view = new View();
    $view->setViewsDir($config->application->viewsDir);
    $view->registerEngines(array(

            '.volt' => function ($view, $di) use ($config) {

                    $volt = new VoltEngine($view, $di);

                    $volt->setOptions(array(
                            'compiledPath' => $config->application->cacheDir,
                            'compiledSeparator' => '_',
                            'compileAlways' => $config->application->debug
                        ));

                    $compiler = $volt->getCompiler();


                    $compiler->addFunction(
                                        'last',
                                        function ($resolvedArgs) use ($compiler) {
                                           return 'array_pop('. $resolvedArgs .')';
                                        }
                    );

                    return $volt;
                }
        ));

    return $view;
}, true);
```

And in Volt for example

```
{{ last(['1', '2', '3']) }}
```

And I really stuck on this problem, because I have pretty a lot of custom functions and I do need them. Tried to debug it, but, as soon as volt tried to parse line with custom function, process die.

Phalcon bug submitted. Solution: totally disable xdebug for current build. More here: https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/pull/120

Comment: I've used custom functions a lot with my previous and current Phalcon projects. Never had any similar issues, but I was always using Ubuntu, not CentOS.

Comment: Problem solved. xdebug + phlacon issue. https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/pull/120

Comment: We encountered this issue with the combination of PHP 5.5, Phalcon 1.3.4 and Xdebug 2.2.5. Was resolved by updating Xdebug to 2.2.7.